# ElasticSearch First and Last Value within Date Range along with other aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data indexed in elastic search like this, and this is the output am expecting where the data is grouped on sku_id, I need average rank for the entire date range, and within the date range, first value of last_7days_avg_rank and last value of last_7days_avg_rank w.r.t the date as 2 separate fields like shown below

Can someone please let me know, if this is possible in elastic search ? right now am doing this computation at service layer, but since the response times have become UN-acceptable, I want to move this logic to ES itself, but not able to figure out how to achieve this ?

Input:

```
 date     sku_id last_7days_avg_rank rank 
 20180101  S1      200                200
 20180102  S1      210                200
 20180105  S1      220                200
 20180108  S1      230                200

 20180101  S2      180                300
 20180103  S2      200                300
 20180106  S2      250                300
 20180107  S2      300                300
```

Expected Output:

```
sku  first_val_last7day_avg  last_val_last7days_avg  avg(rank)   
S1    200                       230                  200
S2    180                       300                  300
```

Thanks!

Comment: And how do you "define" what the date range is?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Date range will come as a filter, for example if user has selected to filter the records between 20180101 and 20180107, then for S1 I want last_7days_avg_rank as of 20180101 as first_value and last_7days_avg_rank as of 20180107 as last_value and the same should apply to S2, S3 and so on and apart from fetching first and last value, I need to perform some other aggregations as well, like for example avg rank for that product during that period. Hope I made it clear ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. The answer below, though, does a good job on addressing your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can get desired result using aggregation

```
{

   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "GROUP": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "sku_id"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "AVG_RANK": {
               "avg": {
                  "field": "rank"
               }
            },
            "FIRST_7_RANK": {
               "top_hits": {
                  "size": 1,
                  "sort": [
                     {
                        "my_date": {
                           "order": "asc"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            "LAST_7_RANK": {
               "top_hits": {
                  "size": 1,
                  "sort": [
                     {
                        "my_date": {
                           "order": "desc"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can get following result as output:

```
 "aggregations": {
      "GROUP": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "S1",
               "doc_count": 40,
               "LAST_7_RANK": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 40,
                     "max_score": null,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "index_name",
                           "_type": "type_name",
                           "_id": "AWI9MU6JeKRzn3ttxGOr",
                           "_score": null,
                           "_source": {
                              "my_date": "2018-01-08",
                              "sku_id": "S1",
                              "last_7days_avg_rank": 230,
                              "rank": 200
                           },
                           "sort": [
                              1515369600000
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "AVG_RANK": {
                  "value": 200
               },
               "FIRST_7_RANK": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 40,
                     "max_score": null,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "index_name",
                           "_type": "type_name",
                           "_id": "AWI9LYVpeKRzn3ttxGOQ",
                           "_score": null,
                           "_source": {
                              "my_date": "20180101",
                              "sku_id": "S1",
                              "last_7days_avg_rank": 200,
                              "rank": 200
                           },
                           "sort": [
                              20180101
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "S2",
               "doc_count": 40,
               "LAST_7_RANK": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 40,
                     "max_score": null,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "index_name",
                           "_type": "type_name",
                           "_id": "AWI9MU6JeKRzn3ttxGOv",
                           "_score": null,
                           "_source": {
                              "my_date": "2018-01-07",
                              "sku_id": "S2",
                              "last_7days_avg_rank": 300,
                              "rank": 300
                           },
                           "sort": [
                              1515283200000
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "AVG_RANK": {
                  "value": 300
               },
               "FIRST_7_RANK": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 40,
                     "max_score": null,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "index_name",
                           "_type": "type_name",
                           "_id": "AWI9LYVpeKRzn3ttxGOU",
                           "_score": null,
                           "_source": {
                              "my_date": "20180101",
                              "sku_id": "S2",
                              "last_7days_avg_rank": 180,
                              "rank": 300
                           },
                           "sort": [
                              20180101
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Above result creates two buckets(groups) for S1 and S2. and within each bucket you can get average rank of that group in AVG_RANK field, for **first_val_last7day_avg** you need to trace value of "FIRST_7_RANK"-> "hits"->"hits"->"_source"->"rank" and similarly for **last_val_last7days_avg** you need to trance value of "LAST_7_RANK"-> "hits"->"hits"->"_source"->"rank"
I hope this might help you

Comment: Hi, this answers my question, any idea, how can we avoid the hits array and instead just get the absolute value ?

Comment: sorry But I don't know any other better solution

Comment: You can limit what the `_source` is showing inside `top_hits` by using something like this: `"_source": {"includes": "last_7days_avg_rank"},` and to have in the end something like this: `"FIRST_7_RANK": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {"includes": "last_7days_avg_rank"}, 
            "sort": [
              {
                "my_date": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }`

Comment: Thanks @AndreiStefan, will try this and torzonhot, no problem and thank you, I am accepting the answer